# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

**Edited**: This error only occurs when I'm using Chrome. If I switch to Safari or FireFox, my server code works OK.

Here's the error log. Please help. I'm playing with the Google OAuth 2.0 API and there's something wrong after Google calls my server back.

Let me know if you need more information to diagnose. (I'm a super newbie so I've no idea what to paste here...)

Besides, **114.247.XXX.YYY** is my local office IP, with which I'm browsing websites and accessing remote servers.

```
2012/06/28 09:54:08 [error] 2170#0: *21 upstream sent too big header
while reading response header from upstream, client: **114.247.XXX.YYY**,
server: my_domain_name.com, request: "GET
/login-callback/google?state=my_randomly_generated_state&code=my_google_authorization_code
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "my_domain_name.com"
```

Comment: Try to catch raw http data with tcpdump and find out which headers are too big.

Comment: You can fix it by adjusting the *proxy* values, like [this page](http://www.howtoforge.com/nginx-upstream-sent-too-big-header-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i' had this problem too, but in every browser.

Validate if you are not listen a socket.

nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

The solution for me was:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
[...]
location ~ \.php$ {
  root /your/site/root;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  #IF you are using a socket change the line above for thise one:
  #fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

  ###to be sure validate on /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
  ####listen = 127.0.0.1:9000 #not a socket
  ####listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock #listen a socket


  # add these two lines:
  fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
  fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}
[...]
}
$sudo service nginx restart
```

Source: [click here](http://shikii.net/blog/firephp-on-nginx-502-bad-gateway/)

Answer (score 0):

change the localhost with your VPS IP. Worked for me